# What is "send link " option in tor browser?

Tags: tor

When you browse using TOR and right click on any webpage, you see an option "send link". I tried it but nothing happened visibly. What does that option do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor doesn't have its own browser; I am guessing you are using the modified Firefox from Tor's "Browser Bundle".

In Firefox, the "Send Link" option normally launches a mail client in "compose message" mode, with the link's target automatically copied to the new message's body.

It could be that the Tor browser is configured to never launch anything, but the option wasn't removed completely.